Flutter Web not building because of Firebase Analytics and Firebase Remote Config
My app is currently not building anymore in web. I am getting these messages:

../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_analytics_web-0.5.5+21/lib/interop/analytics_interop.dart:22:10: Error: Type 'PromiseJsImpl' not found.
external PromiseJsImpl isSupported();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Here are my Firebase version:
  # Firebase
  firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.8
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
  firebase_analytics: ^10.8.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7
  cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  firebase_remote_config: ^4.4.4

And I am currently on Flutter 3.19.6 with SDK set to sdk: '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0'.
I am a bit lost here because I don't get what the error messages are saying.
I already tried flutter pub cache clean and a normal flutter clean.

t’s a good idea to include code, errors and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at No Images Please

flutter clean and then flutter pub upgrade fixed it for me.

I tried so many solutions but did not get the solutions so i tried to remove flutter core flutter auth and cloud firestore packages and then again add them using terminal so it works firn
